# Unreal Engine 4 and C++. Attacking function is fine until if statement is used to only attack when a weapon is equiped

Tags: c++, function, unreal-engine4

I am new to this but I am pretty sure this is a coding question. I am currently following a tutorial in creating a gladiator game in unreal engine. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyBO4p4k_vY&t=2s)

I followed everything to the exact instructions. The problem i ran into is when i code my character to attack with a weapon. I deduced it down to this.

```
void APlayerCharacter::TriggerAttack()
{   
  Attack();
}
```

This triggers the animation to attack with and without the weapon. Meaning that Attacking works. The next step in the tutorial is to only attack when you have a weapon. This is the part that stumps me.

```
void APlayerCharacter::TriggerAttack(){ 

  if (MyWeaponActor){
    Attack();
  }
}
```

The if statement when added does not let me attack at all even when I collided and equipped the weapon. Which leads me to believe that it is the Weapon Item itself. The **ArenaCharacter.cpp** holds the functions to pick up items and attack and the **PickableWeapon.cpp** is the weapon i coded. Is there something I am missing that I am not doing?

```
// ArenaCharacter.cpp

bool AArenaCharacter::PickWeapon(APickableWeapon * pickedWeapon)
{

if (!pickedWeapon)
    return false;

if (!MyWeaponActor) {

    if (pickedWeapon->AttachItemTo(GetMesh(), TEXT("WeaponPoint")) == true) {

        MyWeaponActor = pickedWeapon;
        WeaponCollider = MyWeaponActor->GetDamageBox();

        WeaponCollider->SetCollisionEnabled(ECollisionEnabled::NoCollision);

        return true;

    }
}
return false;
}


// PickableWeapon.cpp

#include "PickableWeapon.h"
#include "Components/SphereComponent.h"
#include "Components/SkeletalMeshComponent.h"
#include "Components/BoxComponent.h"

APickableWeapon::APickableWeapon() {

RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("Root"));

MySphere = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("Sphere"));
MySphere->AttachToComponent(RootComponent, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);

MySkeletalMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<USkeletalMeshComponent>(TEXT("Skeletal Mesh Hammer"));
MySkeletalMesh->AttachToComponent(MySphere, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);


DamageBox = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("Damage Box"));
DamageBox->AttachToComponent(MySphere, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);
}

void APickableWeapon::BeginPlay()
{

}

UBoxComponent * APickableWeapon::GetDamageBox() const
{
  return DamageBox;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're using visual studio, the first thing to do is step through your pickup function and make sure it executes correctly. If it does you could set a data breakpoint on `MyWeaponActor` and see if it's null'd out somehow. Then if still, nothing, the next step would be to be compare the memory address of the chapter picking up the weapon, and the character receiving a do damage event and so on... I know that's not an immediate answer, but you should learn your debugger inside out, unreal will be a miserable expirence otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! That really helped, it at least gives me somewhere to lead on to as well as learn the debugging process instead of banging my head!